# How to report progress of download speed and other information using httpclient?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to calculate download speed download size so far our of total download per file but not sure how to do it in the progresschanged event.

The HttpClientDownloadWithProgress class :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class HttpClientDownloadWithProgress : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _downloadUrl;
    private readonly string _destinationFilePath;

    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public delegate void ProgressChangedHandler(long? totalFileSize, long totalBytesDownloaded, double? progressPercentage);

    public event ProgressChangedHandler ProgressChanged;

    public HttpClientDownloadWithProgress(string downloadUrl, string destinationFilePath)
    {
        _downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        _destinationFilePath = destinationFilePath;
    }

    public async Task StartDownload()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1) };

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_downloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            await DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(response);
    }

    private async Task DownloadFileFromHttpResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

        using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            await ProcessContentStream(totalBytes, contentStream);
    }

    private async Task ProcessContentStream(long? totalDownloadSize, Stream contentStream)
    {
        var totalBytesRead = 0L;
        var readCount = 0L;
        var buffer = new byte[8192];
        var isMoreToRead = true;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
        {
            do
            {
                var bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    isMoreToRead = false;
                    TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
                    continue;
                }

                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                readCount += 1;

                if (readCount % 100 == 0)
                    TriggerProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead);
            }
            while (isMoreToRead);
        }
    }

    private void TriggerProgressChanged(long? totalDownloadSize, long totalBytesRead)
    {
        if (ProgressChanged == null)
            return;

        double? progressPercentage = null;
        if (totalDownloadSize.HasValue)
            progressPercentage = Math.Round((double)totalBytesRead / totalDownloadSize.Value * 100, 2);

        ProgressChanged(totalDownloadSize, totalBytesRead, progressPercentage);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and using it in form1 :

at the top :

```
private List<string> videosLinks = new List<string>();
```

and

```
async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            var downloadFileUrl = "http://212.183.159.230/512MB.zip";
            var destinationFilePath = @"d:\Test\512MB.zip";

            using (var client = new HttpClientDownloadWithProgress(downloadFileUrl, destinationFilePath))
            {
                client.ProgressChanged += (totalFileSize, totalBytesDownloaded, progressPercentage) => {
                    label1.Text = $"{progressPercentage}% ({totalBytesDownloaded}/{totalFileSize})";
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)progressPercentage;
                };

                await client.StartDownload();
            }
        }
```

button click event :

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DownloadFile();
    }
```

The problem is that the download is stopping each few seconds then resuming the download the progressBar is not increment with the label1.Text progress. the download is not smooth.

when i'm downloading the file from a browser it's downloading it smooth fast.

Comment: This might be useful https://gist.github.com/dalexsoto/9fd3c5bdbe9f61a717d47c5843384d11

Comment: @JiriVolejnik i tried it and using it the example in the link you provided and i edited my question with it but it's having some problems.  it's working in general but not smooth.

Comment: by not smooth, do you mean it jumps all once or , do you mean it steps for each event call?

Comment: @Jodrell jump. the progressBar not always moving up with the text in the label1 sometimes the text in label1 not change but the progressBar keep moving up sometimes everything stop for few seconds then continue.  when i'm downloading it in chrome for example i see in downloads the progressBar of the chrome moving with the other information smoothly.  in my code there is some delays.

Comment: @Jodrell i checked now again and i see that when it's downloading in my code it's not async at all.  the button is frozen and everything else i can only shut down the application through the visual studio.

Comment: I suspect that you are releasing the thread asynchronously but the work is not running in the background, so the GUI updates are not running concurrently.

Comment: you can use `Task.Run` to do the download on a background thread but, as the background thread gets progress events you'll need to makes cross-thread calls to the GUI thread to update the GUI. That way the download will happen in the background, the GUI will update inline with progress and the GUI will remain responsive to user interaction.

Comment: Or you can use a [background worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) where the work would be your download.

Comment: @Jodrell the problem with backgroundworker i think it's not supporting resuming for the downloads.  i have a nice downloader with webclient and progress report. the reason i wanted to try hhtpclient is to have the resume option.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi I think you are conflating two things. HttpClient can be used to do the work in the background but that is a separate concern to providing information and control to the user via the GUI. Its a coincidence that the ProgressChanged event occurs on multiple types.